# try-catch with ArrayLsit not working

Tags: java, arraylist, try-catch

Here's an example of the flow of my program:

```
Enter an issuer ID# (6 digits): 12345

java.io.IOException: Invalid issuer ID

Enter an issuer ID# (6 digits): 987

java.io.IOException: Invalid issuer ID

Enter an issuer ID# (6 digits): 555

java.io.IOException: Invalid issuer ID

Enter an issuer ID# (6 digits): 456456
```

And here is my code:

```
public static ArrayList<HW6Re_doHW4> getarray() throws IOException
{
    int size;
    ArrayList<HW6Re_doHW4> card;
    String id;
    HW6Re_doHW4 temp = new HW6Re_doHW4();
    boolean j = false;

    System.out.printf("Enter the number of elements in the array: ");
    size = scanner.nextInt();
    if(size < 1)
    {
        size = 1;
    }
    card = new ArrayList<HW6Re_doHW4>(size);
    while(j == false)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.printf("Enter an issuer ID# (6 digits): ");
            id = scanner.next();
            for(int i = 0; i < card.size(); i++)
            {                   
                temp.createcard(id);                
                card.add(temp);
            }
            j = true;
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            j = false;
        }
    }

    return card;
}
```

The ID# should ask again, but my output just stops. I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Enter the number of elements in the array: 0

Enter an issuer ID# (6 digits): 12345

Answer (score 0):

What did you think was going to happen...

You have:

```
while(j==false) {
    System.out.printf("Enter an issuer ID# (6 digits): ");
    id = scanner.next();
    for(int i = 0; i < card.size(); i++)
        {                   
            temp.createcard(id);                
            card.add(temp);
        }
    j = true;
}
```

So as soon as you ask for an ID and take it in, you set j equal to true. Which stops everything because your condition for the `while` loop is that j must be false...

Just get rid of `j = true;`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have conflated two loops, and you only need one from `0` to `size`. Something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // <-- card.size() starts at 0.
  try {
    System.out.printf("Enter an issuer ID# (6 digits): ");
    id = scanner.next();
    // temp.createcard(id); // <-- probably not.                
    card.add(new HW6Re_doHW4(id)); // <-- something like.
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    i--;
  }
}
```